# Is there an $\epsilon$- contraction map which is not a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f$ be a map on metric space $(X,d)$.

For $\epsilon>0$, the map $f$ is called $\epsilon$- contraction, if there is $0<L<1$ such that $d(f(x), f(y))<Ld(x, y) +\epsilon$.

$f$ is called a contraction map, whenever there is $0<L<1$ such that $d(f(x), f(y))<Ld(x, y)$

> Question: Is there an $\epsilon$-contraction $f$ such that it is not a contraction?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are such maps; for instance the mapping $$f(x) := \sqrt{x}, \qquad x \in X:=[0,1]$$ is an $\epsilon$-contraction for any $\epsilon>0$, but not a contraction. To see this use that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ and Lipschitz continuous on $[\delta,1]$ for any $\delta>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take    $$ f(x) =\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 &  x \leq 0 \\ 
 1 & x > 0
\end{matrix}\right. $$

Then  $ |f(x) - f(y)| \leq 1 \leq L |x -y| + 1  $

by considering $\epsilon =1$, and $0 < L < 1$ then $f$ is $\epsilon-$contraction, but not Lipschitz (since it is discontinuous)

Comment: As far as I understand the OP wants to have a mapping which is an $\epsilon$-contraction for **any** $\epsilon>0$ (but not a contraction).

Comment: @saz    What ? He fixes epsilon before $x,y$.   So If that is  the  case for any $\epsilon > 0$   you can  let  $ \epsilon \to 0$, then you get lipschitzian function

Comment: No, we don't because the constant L depends on $\epsilon$.